# Permission denied error while accessing firebase functions

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a firebase cloud function (http function) which i could access successfully using postman tool, but when i try to access through client sdk from my android application i always get a permission denied error:

> W/System.err: com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: PERMISSION_DENIED
>   04-19 15:18:00.258 3118-3118/com.abc.xyz W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions$2.onResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-functions@@16.3.0:273)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:206)
>           at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Here is the code i used to access the function

```
private fun saveInstallationId(key: String, userId : String, installationKey : String) : Task<String> {
    val data = hashMapOf(
            "key" to key,
            "installationId" to installationKey,
            "userId" to userId

    )

    return functions
            .getHttpsCallable("setInstallationId")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith { task ->
                val result = task.result?.data as String
                result               
}
```

I think i am missing some headers, is it possible to set header parameters using client sdk?